# Sequence of smooth function for a less smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open, and $f \in C^1(\Omega)$. I need to find a sequence $f_n: \Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ such that both the derivatives of $f_n$ and the functions $f_n$ converge to the derivatives of $f$ and $f$. Is there a standard way of doing this?

I want the sequences to be bounded.

Comment: This will not be possible, unless you assume something in the direction of $f \equiv 0$ on $\partial \Omega$ (in the sense of being able to extend f continuously in this way).

Comment: Does 4. require that the sequences are uniformly bounded? Or only that each of the functions is bounded? Typo: $f_n : \Omega \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: @PaulFrost There is $C$ such that $\forall n, \forall x$ we have $|f_n(x)|\leq C$ (and thanks for noting the typo)

Comment: Then $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded and you should assume that $f$ is bounded.